# All variable names on one column in a csv-file

Tags: r, tidy

I have all variable names on one column and underneath it, there are all corresponding values. Each variable name and value are separated by a comma. I would like to have all variable names on separate columns and underneath each value corresponding to a variable for each id. How do I get them separate?

Thanks!

[image: mystery file]

Comment: You need to specify the comma as the separator when reading in your csv file.

Comment: As a quick work-around you may be able to read the file into Excel and just use the Text to Columns wizard on the Data ribbon.